# Use complex numbers to simplify this trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I was able to simplify this expression using transformation formulae. The answer turned out to be

$$\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)+
\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)$$

How could this be simplified using complex numbers(assume that I now know little to nothing about transformation formulae but only the complex definition of sines and cosines)